# using multiple variables in foreach?

Tags: c#

I have the following `foreach`:

```cs
var tables = new List<String>() {"Source"...

foreach (var table in tables)
{
    if (Context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().ToLower().Contains(table))
    {
        AccessControlRule(
          String.Format("{0}ID", table),
          "select {table}ID from {table} where IsDelete = 0", AccessPermission.Allow);
    }
    else
    {
        AccessControlRule(String.Format("{0}ID", table),
          "select {table}ID from {table} where IsDelete = 1 OR IsDelete = null",
          AccessPermission.Allow);
    }
```

This generates `{table}ID`. This is  supposed to be the `table Primary Key`, and my `foreach` will get it correct if the `PK` for **Source** was **SourceID**

Now, what if the PK for **Source table** was **abcID**?   How could I add a second variable in my foreach containing all tables' primary Keys?

Currently, I have those variables as follow:

```cs
var tablesPK = new List<String>(){"abcID"...} <---- PK
var tables = new List<String>() {"Source"...} <---- table name
```

Comment: Consider using LINQ `Zip`?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, but maybe you don't even need a `foreach` at all. Do you need to iterate over a collection of values, or can you determine from the URL which table matches your condition some other way? Can the URL contain more than one table? What happens if the you have two tables: Pet and PetOwners? If the URL specifies PetOwners it will match both table names, perhaps unintentionally, since a URL that contains PetOwners also contains Pet?

Comment: @Yoshuwa - this question was closed (incorrectly) before I could answer but you don't need to have multiple loops as that isn't your real problem.  Since they  primary key names don't always follow the same naming convention, create a dictionary<string, string> of tablename/index combination and just loop through that - then you only have one loop and you are able to accomodate different primary key names.